# Is there a smart contract to send my balance to a new wallet once it reaches a certain level?

Tags: transactions, wallets

Is there a smart contract or anything that could send my balance to a new wallet once it reaches a certain level?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, no smart contract can send Ether from your wallet without storing your private key inside the contract. Which, of course, is a very bad idea.

But it's fairly easy to write a smart contract which sends its balance to your wallet address when the balance reaches a certain treshold. It just needs to be done when something happens. For example when someone sends the contract ether, it would be something like this:

```
function() public payable {
    uint limitBalance = 100 ether;
    if (address(this).balance > limitBalance) {
        address receiver = 0x0123;
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```